# My C code working on Windows perfectly but isn't working on Ubuntu exactly

Tags: compiling, c++

Example lines from input file:

```
abc@gmail.com Andee SMITH 1234
ADAM abc@gmail.com Andeee 21654
Anderea abc@gmail.com SAMMY 3524654
abc@gmail.com Andi BROWN 1245
Andie abc@gmail.com KNOWY 2485
Andra abc@gmail.com BRUCE 52445
Andrea abc@gmail.com 246574 DENNIS
2154 Andreana abc@gmail.com CHASE
Andree 21524 SIERRRA abc@gmail.com
Andrei 154 MONDY abc@gmail.com
4564765 Andria MALLE abc@gmail.com
78 Andriana abc@gmail.com WALLS
579874 abc@gmail.com Andriette MOUNT
52445 abc@gmail.com Andromache FRASSER
5478645 abc@gmail.com Andy MCFLY
```

```
//This program about scanning names,surnames ext. from disordered txt file and creating new ordered txt file.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{

char  id[50];
char name[50];
char lname[50];
char mail[50];

}Person;

int main(){

    char str[250];
    int count=0;
    char c;
    char previous;
    int index =0;
    int i,m,l;
    int j,k=0;
    Person person[300];
    char str1[250];
    char in[1];
    char p;
    Person temp;


    FILE *file= fopen("hw4_disordered_people.txt","r");


    while(c!=EOF){  // how many of struct

        c= fgetc(file);

        if(c=='\n'){

        ++count;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    //person *person= (person*)malloc(count+1*sizeof(person));

    file = fopen( "hw4_disordered_people.txt" , "r");
    while(fgets(str1,sizeof(str1),file)){
        ++index;
        for (j = 0; str1[j] != '\n'; ++j)
        {
            if (str1[j] != ' ' && str1[j+1] != '\n')
            {
                str[k] = str1[j];
                k++;
            }
            else  if (k > 0 )
            {
                if (str1[j+1] == '\n')
                {
                    str[k] = str1[j];
                    k++;
                }
                str[k] = '\0';
                k=0;




                if(str[0] >= '0' && str[0] <='9')
                {
                    strcpy(person[index].id,str);
                    //printf("%s ",person[index].id);
                    strcpy(str,"");

                }
                else if (str[1] >= 'A' && str[1] <='Z')
                {

                    if(strlen(person[index].lname) > 0){
                        //printf(" %s ",str);
                        strcat(person[index].lname," ");
                        strcat(person[index].lname,str);
                        strcpy(str,"");
                    }
                    else{
                        strcpy(person[index].lname,str);
                        //printf("%s ",person[index].lname);
                        strcpy(str,"");

                    }

                }
                else if ((str[1] >= 'a' && str[1] <='z') && (str[0] >= 'A' && str[0] <='Z'))
                {

                    if(strlen(person[index].name) > 0){
                        //printf(" %s ",str);
                        strcat(person[index].name," ");
                        strcat(person[index].name,str);
                        strcpy(str,"");
                    }
                    else{
                        strcpy(person[index].name,str);
                        //printf("%s  ",person[index].name);
                        strcpy(str,"");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(person[index].mail,str);
                    //printf("%s ",person[index].mail);
                    strcpy(str,"");
                }

            }

        }
    }
     FILE *fp;

          fp=fopen("OrderedList.txt","w");
          for(i=1;i<=count;++i){


          fprintf(fp,"%s %s %s %s\n",person[i].name,person[i].lname,person[i].mail,person[i].id);
         }
}
```

Comment: On windows output file exactly i want but on ubuntu there are newlines in some irrelevant places.

Comment: I'd guess the input file has improper line endings (`\r\ņ` (DOS) vs. `\n` (Unix)).

Comment: Should i use /r/n instead of \n checking for newlines?

Comment: @karel  I don't think this is suitable as duplicate, especially since OP's asking about C code and how it should work between OS's

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add some sample lines of  your input.

Comment: @PerlDuck How can i add txt file

Comment: [Edit] your post, paste (some lines of) your file, select the pasted text and format is as code (by either clicking the `{}` symbol in the editor's toolbar or hitting CTRL+K).

Comment: While you are at it, you should **also add what error you face**. Currently the question only contains a C program and the title says it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Your program has many errors in it, here are a few:

```
FILE *file= fopen("hw4_disordered_people.txt","r");


while(c!=EOF){  // how many of struct
```

Here you don't check if opening the file succeeded and you begin to make use of the uninitialized variable `c`, which can technically have any value sitting in memory assigned to it. Even with the assumed value of `0` this is also still wrong since this assumes that a file is at least 1 byte large meaning this program may do strange things with an empty file passed to it.

```
while(c!=EOF){  // how many of struct
    c = fgetc(file);

    if(c=='\n'){
      ++count;
    }
}
```

The correct way to write this would be closer to:

```
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
  ++count;
}
```

It's also worth noting that this portion of the program can be replaced by using the `wc -l` command, which counts how many lines exist in a file.

```
if (str1[j+1] == '\n')
```

There is no guarantee that `j+1` is a valid index into this array.

```
char str[250];
```

There is no guarantee that a line in the file won't be 248 characters or longer (including the newline and null terminator)

```
Person person[300];
```

There is no guarantee that the input file will be 300 or less lines.

```
str[k] = '\0';
```

`k` may now point outside the bounds of the character array, although the input needed to do it is a pretty specific edge case.

```
strcpy(person[index].id,str);
```

Buffer overflow if `index` is out of range (300)

```
for(i=1;i<=count;++i){
```

This likely attempts to access data outside the bounds of the array. The fact you increment early in the loop and discard index 0 of the array is strange, but not technically an error, but the fact that you are willing to access `count + 1` as a valid address is an error and if you were using `malloc` without a fixed array size or processing a file with 300 inputs this would segmentation fault / crash the program.

You should compile your code with `gcc -Wall` and you will likely get a lot of these warnings automatically.

If your course material allows it you should be using C++ with the Standard Template Library (STL) in which case this entire program would be a few lines of code that have strong guarantees that it won't have many of the memory errors presented here since it would use `std::string` and `std::istream` to make this less of an issue along with `std::unordered_map` to make lookups faster.

Comment: This program for my C programming homework so I can't use STL. I will try use malloc instead of fixed arrays.Thanks for the advices.